# Verb agreement in "Where is the Messiah and his Kingdom?"

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number, verb-agreement, coordinating-conjunctions, compound-subjects

> Where is the Messiah and his Kingdom?

I think it should be "Where are the Messiah and his kingdom"; it just sounds better!
But my friends and even a teacher claim that "is" would be correct.

Comment: "Where _is_ ..." _sounds_ better to me!

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13320/where-is-versus-where-are,

Answer (score 3):

Formal agreement requires *are*. Those who argue for *is* will see 'the Messiah and his Kingdom' as a unitary concept, thus allowing notional agreement by means of the singular.

Comment: It seems to me you could reasonably use *"is"* if you have a comma after *"Messiah"*. So if we allow that discarding a comma which imho isn't exactly **vital**, it's just valid elision from *"Where is the Messiah and [**where is**] his Kingdom?"*

Comment: @FumbleFingers- That's exactly how I took it as well.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me you could reasonably use "is" if you have a comma after "Messiah". So if we allow discarding a comma (which imho isn't exactly vital), it's just valid elision from...

> *"Where is the Messiah and [where is] his Kingdom?"*

FWIW, I just Googled ["where are the queen and her"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22where%20are%20the%20queen%20and%20her%22&oq=%22where%20are%20the%20queen%20and%20her%22&aqs=chrome.0.57j60l2.834&sugexp=chrome,mod=18&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) (1 result), and ["where is the queen and her"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22where%20are%20the%20queen%20and%20her%22&oq=%22where%20are%20the%20queen%20and%20her%22&aqs=chrome.0.57j60l2.834&sugexp=chrome,mod=18&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&tbo=d&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22where%20is%20the%20queen%20and%20her%22&oq=%22where%20is%20the%20queen%20and%20her%22&gs_l=serp.3...53191.54348.0.55110.5.5.0.0.0.0.69.291.5.5.0.les;..0.0...1c.1.yNyPjE1RA7g&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&bvm=bv.1355534169,d.d2k&fp=a5d91bad1ac8234a&bpcl=40096503&biw=1412&bih=897) (3 results). Not much to go on, but it does suggest the singular verb form isn't *that* ridiculous.