# Can "time and convenience" take singular notional agreement in this sentence?

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement, coordinating-conjunctions, compound-subjects

> Time and convenience (is/are) turning friends and acquaintances away from our doors.

Which is better in this context, 'is' or 'are'? Can the answer to this question be 'is' based on notional agreement?

Comment: Deepam, if you are still there, could you edit your question to add some more information about what this sentence is supposed to mean? I find it a bit puzzling. Is it something like "We have been forced to turn friends and acquaintances from our doors because that saves time and is more convenient for us"?

Answer (score 1):

Are

I have not encountered in difference in is and are except for is being singular noun/s and are being for plural noun/s.  And if there is some difference I don't know about, that would mean that there is a confliction/paradox between the usage of is and are.

The nouns combine to form like a plural combined noun.

Comment: The OP refers to notional agreement; a topic that has come up on this site before in the following questions: "[Verb agreement in 'Where is the Messiah and his Kingdom?'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/94987/verb-agreement-in-where-is-the-messiah-and-his-kingdom)", "[Agreement With Compound Subjects Joined by And](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/117346/agreement-with-compound-subjects-joined-by-and)"

Comment: @sumelic I don't see how that disproves my point, time and convince aren't referring to 1 thing but rather two things.  That "Bangers and mash" example was referring to one thing.

Comment: Hmm, I wasn't really trying to disprove your answer, just add more information since you said "I have not encountered in difference in is and are except for is being singular noun/s and are being for plural noun/s. And if there is some difference I don't know about..." I'm not sure actually what "time and convenience" really means in the OP's sentence. I will leave a comment asking for clarification

Comment: @user58712: just like how you argue that "bangers and mash" is referring to one thing, "time and convenience" can be argued to be "**[the consideration of]** time and convenience", which is then also referring to one thing (the consideration).