# Which is grammatically correct? Open or opens?

Tags: grammar

1)The quest of finding methods of expression that is authentic to oneself open up doors

2)The quest of finding methods of expression that is authentic to oneself open**s** up doors

Comment: Thank you for the correction! Why is "opens" correct instead of "open"?

Comment: Is "art and the process of creation presents to me a world of imagination" correct?

Comment: That is a bit more complicated. When you have multiple noun phrases joined by "and", they are usually treated as a plural subject. See the answer to the following post: [Can “time and convenience” take singular notional agreement in this sentence?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/410923) Exceptions to that principle may exist in certain contexts for some speakers.

Comment: So "art and the process of creation" is plural combined noun, thus present is correct instead of presents?

Comment: Yes, "art and the process of creation" would most likely be treated as a plural noun phrase that takes a plural verb ("present").

Comment: The quest for finding methods of expression that are authentic to oneself opens up new doors.

Comment: If it is expression that is authentic, then "is" is ok.

Answer (score 2):

Neither is correct. "The quest of finding methods of expression that **are** authentic to oneself **opens** up doors" would be grammatical.

"Quest" is a singular noun: "The quest opens up doors". "Methods" is a plural noun: "Methods that are authentic".

The other answer suggests using "The quest of finding methods of [expression that is authentic to oneself] opens up doors", where "that is authentic to oneself" is taken as a relative clause modifying "expression". That is *technically* a possible structure for the sentence, and the use of "is authentic..." is correct for that structure, but it doesn't sound natural to me at all.

Answer (score 0):

The second one is correct.

In

> The quest opens up doors.

the verb *opens up* agrees in person and number with the subject *quest*.

The sentence doesn't require *are* if both the prepositional phrase

> of finding methods of expression

and the restrictive relative clause

> that is authentic to oneself

refer to the noun *quest*.

The meaning of the sentence is that that quest which consists of finding methods of expression and that it is also, or it happens to also be, authentic to oneself, opens up doors.

Comment: Appreciate your detailed explanation!