# `Where's` usage in spoken English

Tags: grammatical-number

One often hears native English speakers use constructs such as "where's my trousers" or (from this forum [in another post](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/13320/49862)) "where is my parents and mothers?"

Is that a case of spoken grammar differing from written grammar, a case of specific variants of English from different regional areas, or just a very frequent error in English (and given the frequency of occurrence are we bordering on a change in spoken grammar)?

The question is not about the "logical" aspects but more about actual usage.

** Edited on 2017/Feb/13: changed the question to focus on `'s` instead of `is` form in spoken english **

Comment: As a native speaker, I've neither heard nor used "Where is..." instead of "Where are..." for the plural. I could understand where someone *might* confuse "trousers" as one of those strange non-plural plurals, but I can't recall ever hearing it. Certainly not `often`.

Comment: Related: ["there's some towels in the closet"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12865/is-therere-similar-to-theres-a-correct-contraction).

Comment: Oh, and please do make sure to spell *English* correctly on this site. Or elsewhere. Thank you.

Comment: *Where's*, yes, but not *where is*. People don't do that with plurals.

Comment: Andy Stewart has a lot to answer for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wanted to add my approval of the previous answer as an English teacher and native English speaker.

"Where's" is the form most people actually use when speaking. It would sound strange to a native speaker to hear "Where is my trousers?" Saying "where's my trousers" is fine, but the correct grammar as you know would be "Where are my trousers?"

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please note that this is not a discussion forum, but a Q&A site; please do not submit an answer only to lend support to an existing answer. I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for a better understanding of how Stack Exchange operates.

Comment: Hi, thanks for confirming what I had heard and the actual grammar. Maybe,  to avoid anathema from some of the members of the forum, should I have used the apostrophe which is indeed closer to the spoken form.

Comment: Yes, the apostrophe was the only thing that changed most responses, I'm sure.

Answer (score 1):

Singular *where is* is often contracted to *where's*:

> Where is my coat?
>  Where's my coat?

The plural *where are* can also be contracted (because people tend to contract words when speaking) to *where're*.

> Where are my trousers?
>  Where're my trousers?

However, this is more awkward to say (and certainly looks strange written down). It seems people stick in an 's' to ease the words together, regardless of correct grammar.

> Where's my trousers?

Perhaps you have heard this and have interpreted it as *Where is.* But I have never heard people say (clearly spoken) *Where is* + plural, and you should not write it formally.

Comment: Indeed I had only heard 'Where's' instead of 'Where is', thanks for the explanation.